# Java,hashmap,cant print the value(object)

Tags: java, printing, hashmap

My code:

```
HashMap<Integer,Student> Chemistry= new HashMap<Integer,Student>();
Chemistry.put(3333,"NICK");
for (int keys : Chemistry.keySet()){
             System.out.println(keys + ":"+ Chemistry.get(keys));
 }
```

the output is:

```
3333:Student@4aa298b7
```

Comment: override toString().

Comment: See above comments, but also why are you using a HashMap when you're clearly only using it as an ArrayList?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans because OP doesn't want to store 3333 elements of nothing?

Comment: I'd imagine you actually have `Chemistry.put(3333, new Student("NICK"));`, or similar? You can't put a string value into that map.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's an odd comment. I'm assuming the 3333 is the student number, because storing students with gaps doesn't even make sense, but unless either of us are the OP, we can't answer the why.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you expect every student to study Chemistry?

Comment: What subject they take is not even remotely relevant when the code blind-iterates over the datastructure. I don't see any other code, _maybe_ OP is better off not using a HashMap. But again, neither you nor I know this. We can invent all sorts of "what ifs", none of which matter because it's not either of our code.

Comment: i use the hasmap to store the student with their id(as key) and as value i put a  type-student object.the whole concept is to create a student type-object for each student,keeping info about em(name,id,courses etc) and i create a hashmap for some courses(chemistry,math etc) and i store the students who have not pass the certain course

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i want to get used to using hashmaps.Im practising so i dont want the easy way

Answer (score 1):

That's the default implementation on `toString()` you're seeing. You could override it to get something more useful. E.g.:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;

    // Constructors, methods, the whole nine yards...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A student called " + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is i want to print a variable of the object but i print the0 "whole" object?

Comment: @NikosPsilodimitrakopoylos you can implement `toString()` however you want - if `Student` has other attributes, you should include them there too.